# Customizing Scaffolding view Templates in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have followed the steps of creating a custom CShtml Tempalte with MVC 5  in Visual Studio 2013,that is well-worked, but how can i do that in Visual Studio 2017 and an asp.net-core-mvc project?

Comment: Had you tried something?

Comment: yeah of course! I try to use Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final and copy the Templates folder to the root of my project and edit them , but show me nothing in  dropdown template menu after  i clicked AddView.

Comment: Installation of Visual Studio 2017 was done properly?